# How to assign a Class to an array in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, class

I have a little problem I can't figure out. I want to assign a class to an array but vb.net says, on line 7, that I cannot use the keyword 'New' to someArray(2).

How can I simply achieve what I try to do?

```
Public Class Form1

Public Class someClass
    Public someName As String
    Public someNumber As Integer
End Class

Public someRecord As New someClass
Public someArray(2) As New someClass

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    someRecord.someName = "A text"
    someRecord.someNumber = 10
    someArray(0).someName = "A text"
    someArray(0).someNumber = 10
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it works is that you tell it what the array is made of, and then you need to assign an instance of the class to the array element:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Class SomeClass
        Public someName As String
        Public someNumber As Integer
    End Class

    Public someArray(2) As SomeClass

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim someRecord As New SomeClass
        someRecord.someName = "A text"
        someRecord.someNumber = 10
        someArray(0) = someRecord

        ' Fill the rest of the array with default instances...
        For i = 1 To someArray.Length - 1
            someArray(i) = New SomeClass()
        Next


    End Sub

End Class
```